# Group By error: column not contained in aggregate function or Group By clause, but it actually is?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm practicing a bit of SQL because of an exam I've got coming up, and I've run into this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> Column 'DEPOSITO.depo_zona' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I've searched through all the info regarding it, and it's always a column that is missing either in the count() (or whatever other function they use) or the group by. However, in my case, the column 'DEPOSITO.depo_zona' IS in the group by (even though it's not necessary), so I'm scratching my head here, because I really don't know what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
--Cantidad de depósitos en esa zona
(select count(distinct D2.depo_codigo)
from DEPOSITO D2
where D2.depo_zona = D1.depo_zona
group by D2.depo_zona, D2.depo_codigo) CantidadDepositos,
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

UPDATE:
This is the whole query:

```
--Año
select year(Factura.fact_fecha) Año,
--Código de zona
    Z1.zona_codigo CodigoZona,
--Detalle de la zona
    Z1.zona_detalle DetalleZona,
--Cantidad de depósitos en esa zona
    (select count(distinct D2.depo_codigo)
    from DEPOSITO D2
    where D2.depo_zona = D1.depo_zona
    group by D2.depo_zona, D2.depo_codigo) CantidadDepositos,
--Cantidad de empleados de departamentos de esa zona
    (select count(*)
    from Departamento
        join Empleado on Departamento.depa_codigo = Empleado.empl_departamento
    where Departamento.depa_zona = Z1.zona_codigo) CantidadEmpleados,
--Empleado que más vendió en ese año y esa zona
    (select top 1 Factura.fact_vendedor
    from Item_Factura
        join Factura on Factura.fact_numero = Item_Factura.item_numero
            and Factura.fact_sucursal = Item_Factura.item_sucursal
            and Factura.fact_tipo = Item_Factura.item_tipo
        join STOCK on STOCK.stoc_producto = Item_Factura.item_producto
        join DEPOSITO on DEPOSITO.depo_codigo = STOCK.stoc_deposito
    group by Factura.fact_vendedor
    order by sum(Factura.fact_total) desc) EmpleadoEstrella,
--Monto total de venta de esa zona en ese año
    sum(Factura.fact_total) TotalZona,
--Porcentaje de la venta de ese año en esa zona respecto al total vendido de ese año
    sum(Factura.fact_total) * 100/
    (select sum(F1.fact_total)
    from Factura F1
    where year(F1.fact_fecha) = year(Factura.fact_fecha)) PorcentajeVenta
--Ordenar por año y dentro del año por zona con más facturación de mayor a menor
from Factura
    join Item_Factura on Factura.fact_tipo = Item_Factura.item_tipo
        and Item_Factura.item_sucursal = Factura.fact_sucursal
        and Item_Factura.item_numero = Factura.fact_numero
    join STOCK on STOCK.stoc_producto = Item_Factura.item_producto
    join DEPOSITO D1 on D1.depo_codigo = STOCK.stoc_deposito
    join Zona Z1 on Z1.zona_codigo = D1.depo_zona
group by year(Factura.fact_fecha), Z1.zona_codigo, Z1.zona_detalle
order by year(Factura.fact_fecha), sum(Factura.fact_total) desc
```

Comment: I don't understand.  This is not a valid SQL query.  This is probably not a valid scalar subquery either.  `D1` is not defined, for instance.  You should probably simplify your query and put the entire simplified query in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah sorry, my bad. I've just updated the question

Comment: For every row in the outer query, the expression you define for alias `CantidadDepositos` must produce a **single, scalar** value. You cannot use a GROUP BY clause within that subquery since that can generate multiple rows. That subquery is already correlated on depo_zona, but that still leaves a problem with depo_codigo. That probably needs to be correlated to the outer query just like depo_zona.

Comment: Hi @SMor! You mean like this? (select count(*)
 from DEPOSITO D2
 where D2.depo_zona = D1.depo_zona) CantidadDepositos //// Cause it's still giving me the same error :/

Comment: No idea what that means. Effectively, you need to remove the GROUP BY clause completely from that subquery. How to change it to produce the correct result is something you need to work through. I guessed about the correlation - but I don't know your schema, how it is used, and what your subquery represents.

Comment: The reason you get that error is because in the `SELECT` you can only access non-aggregated columns, so your correlated subquery has no access to aggregated columns (columns that are not in the `GROUP BY`). You could move the subquery to an `APPLY`, but then you will need an aggregation on its result. Also, looks like you could do with some window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `count(distinct D2.depo_codigo)`  to `count (*)` or remove `D2.depo_codigo` in group by of your subquery coz that doesn't make any sense you are grouping by 2 columns and having a count on columns of group by simultaneously. Also, using a corelated subquery like this is totally wrong because for that particular group by column inner select should run until that column matches with the outer that's not possible as there will be inconsistent rows even though there's an aggregate it will throw some other error in case you try to resolve this error either place it in a join itself or use CTE approach

Replace the where and it will run as where makes it a corelated subquery in select itself that's not the way to use corelated subquery

Comment: Hi! Yeah, I did that out of desperation. This is the original code, and it still gives me the same error: (select count(*) from DEPOSITO D2 where D2.depo_zona = D1.depo_zona) CantidadDepositos

Answer (score -1):

In the end I had to add DEPOSITO.depo_zona to the group by of the query, not just the subquery. Thanks for all your help!